# React Native: State update not reflecting in immediate function call within onPress event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native component where I'm updating a state variable using a setter function (setSubtractArr) within an onPress event handler. However, I'm facing an issue where the state update doesn't seem to happen synchronously, causing problems when calling another function (endFunction) immediately after the state update.

```
const handlePress = () => {
  // State update
  props.setSubtractArr(prev => prev + (props.workoutInfo.reps * props.workoutInfo.interval / 1000));
  
  // Log the updated value
  console.log('subtractArr:', props.subtractArr);
  
  // Call another function with the updated value
  endFunction(props.subtractArr); // Not reflecting the updated value
};

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
    {/* My TouchableOpacity content */}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

In the above code, the console.log statement outputs the updated value of subtractArr correctly, but when passing props.subtractArr to endFunction, it doesn't reflect the updated value. It appears that the state update is asynchronous and doesn't happen immediately.

How can I ensure that the state update is completed before calling endFunction with the updated value of subtractArr in the onPress event handler?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `endfunction(...)` whenever `props.subtractArr` changes.

Try to add this code to yours:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  endFunction(props.subtractArr);
}, [props.subtractArr]);
```

Comment: But I cant use useEffect since it is in a onPress function and useEffect must be top lvl